# How to get birthday via Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am setting up a Facebook login, and am successfully getting things like `first_name`, `email`, etc. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get birthday. If I call for `birthday` as below, nothing returns.

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'birthday'}, function(response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

If I call `user_birthday` as below, I get this error: `"error":{"message":"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_birthday)`

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'user_birthday'}, function(response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that every user has entered a birthday ?

Comment: Does `birthday_date` work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you did not post your login code and you did not mention permissions, i assume you forgot one important thing: Authorizing with the `user_birthday` permission.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user authorized the app
    }
}, {scope: 'user_birthday', return_scopes: true});
```

`user_birthday` is the permission, `birthday` is the name of the field. If it still doesn´t work, then there is most likely no birthday set. Not sure if it is required.

For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/